# get_metadata WordPress function is not working

Tags: wordpress

```
$transactions = get_metadata( 'post', '', '_pfund_transactions' );
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I specified the type and the key. I also left the object ID blank as I'm not sure what should go there.

Here's an example of the data involved in the meta_value field.

```
a:6:{s:7:"success";s:1:"1";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";s:11:"donor_email";s:16:"test@test.com";s:16:"donor_first_name";s:4:"adsf";s:15:"donor_last_name";s:3:"dfs";s:17:"transaction_nonce";s:22:"xxxxxx";}
```

The result appears to be empty as the statement below is true

```
if (! empty( $transactions ) )
```

Comment: that's where i'm coming from. don't see what i did wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The post ID should be used as the object ID. Also, it looks like you're wanting multiples, so you should pass a 4th argument as false.

I.E; $transactions = get_metadata( 'post', $post_id, '_pfund_transactions', false );

Give that a try!